# JMX: how add description for Operations/Attributes through plain Java

Tags: java, jmx

For a Java App working with JMX I am able to register my custom MBeans, they are available to be used through either JConsole or VisualVM.

Through Spring, with a set of annotations available through the Framework itself, is possible add descriptions for the *Operations* and *Attributes* to be shown through JConsole.

How accomplish the same goal through plain Java? (Spring is **not** involved) here. I already did do a research in StackOverflow and I found some third party solutions, such as:

- [How to add description to JMX MXBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810055/how-to-add-description-to-jmx-mxbean) that refers to [JMX Annotations](http://actimem.com/java/jmx-annotations/)
- [How to add description for MBean method to see it in jmx-console of JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077175/how-to-add-description-for-mbean-method-to-see-it-in-jmx-console-of-jboss) that refers to [Adding descriptions to JMX beans using an annotation wrapper](https://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/)

but seems there is no a direct approach by Java itself.

Is it possible? How?